Same object files for both static and dynamic library
I've a project where I'm building object files without-fPIC for static library libx.a and with -fPIC for dynamic library libx.so .Now I've to compile both source files cpp or c twice and there are 1000s of them.
Now can I build just the -fPIC object files once for both static and dynamic library ?
Do you see any pitfalls with above approach ?
Regards,
Navin

Why don't you just try it?

Using position independent code (PIC) is perfectly fine for static libraries.


Now can I build just the -fPIC object files once for both static and dynamic library ?

You sure can.

Do you see any pitfalls with above approach ?

The pitfall is that on some platforms (notably x86) your archive library will be slightly slower (because PIC code requires extra level of indirection) and slightly larger than if it was built without -fPIC.
Whether the increased code size and runtime overhead matters or not only you can measure and tell.
Usually the overhead is in the 1% range and most of the time it doesn't matter. But if your code runs on 100,000 machines, even 1% may turn into real money.
Also, as this answer shows, the overhead can be quite significant if you are not careful.
